# bootstrap wp-nav closing with $(document).on click but not $('btn-class')

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a chopped up version of bootstrap's jquery navbar. I originally was unable to get the nav to close after it opened just fine, so I added...

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

...which obviously made my nav close when any page element was selected, so I changed $(document) to $('.navbar-toggle'), as shown below, but had no luck getting it to close again.

What am I missing to get the nav to close with just a button click?

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container row hdrMain">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="row verticalAlign">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6"></div>
                        <div class="navbar-header  col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#closeIT">btn</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-9">
                    <div id="closeIT" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <div class="row hdrIcons">
                            <ul>
                              <li>icon</li>
                              <li>icon</li>
                              <li>icon</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!--<?php wp nav function called here?>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

```
<script>         
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.navbar-toggle').on('click',function(e){
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this with **jQuery**:

```
<script>
    function someFunction(){
        $('#closeIT').collapse();
    }
    $('body').on('click', '.navbar-toggle', someFunction); //event-listener
</script>
```

> **EDIT**: You should put the event listener at the end of your javascript
>   file. Here is working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9n6wuo9/2/)
>
> Just put the wrapper inside the navbar-collapse div.

Comment: hmmm, seems to only shrink my header and not fix the button closing

Comment: Can you specify which version of bootstrap you are using?

Comment: I included working JSFiddle. I hope this is what you seek. I included bootstrap 3.3.7 version in it since i don't know which version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit based on comment:**

- Once the toggle content is displayed, the button is overlayed by it, this is preventnig the click behavior to close it.
- Add `z-index: 1;` to `.navbar-toggle` to raise it above it's dropdown content.

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2L11dkdf/)

Comment: Nothing's changed.. the button just seems to disable. I it no longer changes the cursor to pointer

Comment: @gabe1331, edited above, easy tweak 1 css line, add z-index to bring toggler above. Hope helps, regards.